# Accessing ui-router state params from an attribute-type directive (NOT a component)

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

We're upgrading from a very old version of UI Router to v1.0.5, and I'm having an issue trying to replace our deprecated $stateParams uses. To use a simplified example, we have a `unique-name` attribute-type directive we use on a form field to do a validation check to make sure the text in the field is a unique name. The idea is we're either adding a new doohickey or changing the name of an existing doohickey, and we want to ensure that no other doohickey has the same name.

In our old code, we could get the `doohickeyId` value from the `$stateParams` like this:

```
function uniqueName(doohickeySearchService, $stateParams, $q) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function (scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
                ctrl.$asyncValidators.uniqueName = function (modelValue) {
                    // use doohickeySearchService to look up foundDoohickey by name
                    // then...
                    return foundDoohickey.id !== $stateParams.doohickeyId;
                };
            }
        };
    }
```

Probably way over-simplified, but the core of the problem is there: how do we get access to the `doohickeyId` value without using the deprecated `$stateParams`? There's a parent state that's getting it from the url , which is something like `/doohickey/{doohickeyId:int}/edit`, as specified in the state definition.

I can use `$state` to get the `$current` state, and an array of states from the `path` property, and I can even see the `doohickeyId` param in one of the states in the path. Unfortunately, if I take the `value()` of the param, it comes back undefined, even though `$stateParams` has the correct `doohickeyId` value. I've also tried adding `doohickeyId` as a resolve on the parent state, but unfortunately that doesn't give me any data on the attribute-type directive where I need it.

Reading the docs and googling is turning up references to accessing parent data from child *states*, or a component, but I'm trying to get access from an attribute-type directive, not a state/component. Is there a way to do this without giving our code base a major overhaul?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this solution from the UI-Router documentation?

> **Instead of using the global $stateParams service object,**
>
> inject $uiRouterGlobals and use UIRouterGlobals.params
>
> ```
> MyService.$inject = ['$uiRouterGlobals'];
> function MyService($uiRouterGlobals) {
>   return {
>     paramValues: function () {
>       return $uiRouterGlobals.params;
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> **Instead of using the per-transition $stateParams object,**
>
> inject the current Transition (as $transition$) and use Transition.params
>
> ```
> MyController.$inject = ['$transition$'];
> function MyController($transition$) {
>   var username = $transition$.params().username;
>   // .. do something with username
> }
> ```

https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/modules/injectables.html#_stateparams

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for, thanks much! I was googling for it, I read the migration guide repeatedly, and the whole time it was in the docs under "Injectables."

Comment: The new UI Router documentation is not for the faint of heart or the short of patience.

Answer (score 0):

Pass data as the value of your attribute-type directive. Then retrieve it via the `attrs` argument in the link function. Then eval it against scope.

```
<input unique-name="{doohickeyId: doohickeyIdFromStateParams}" />

link: function (scope, elm, attrs) {
    var data = scope.$eval(attrs.uniqueName));

    console.log('My doohickey ID is: ', data.doohickeyId);

}
```

Comment: This works for the (oversimplified) example I gave, but the original code is going to make this a bit more involved. If it's the best available answer, I'll accept it. But is there any way to get to the data like it used to be in `$stateParams`? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer offline, but I wanted to post it here for future reference. The approach we decided to take was to set up our own custom global state service to hold the state params. So in `app/app.js` we've got something like this in `app.run()`:

```
$transitions.onFinish({}, function ($transition$) {
    customStateService.setCurrentStateParams($transition$);
});
```

Then we can inject our `customStateService` wherever we need it, and call a `getCurrentStateParams()` function to retrieve whatever params were available in the most recent successful state transition, similar to how we were previously using `$stateParams`.

Comment: Works, but not the best answer. See the accepted answer for a better solution.